# How does Git branching work in this case?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a repo "sample" with 2 branches "master" and "develop".

I work on "feature-1" and push my changes to the "develop" branch. These changes haven't been merged to "master".

I then work on "feature-2". How do I push just these changes to "master", without pushing "feature-1" as well?

Comment: Please clarify your wording. Git cannot "push to branch". Git can "push to a repository" or "merge into a branch". So, which one is it that you mean with "push to branch"? It helps if you show the commands that you issued.

Comment: From `feature-2`, `git push origin feature-2:master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: you've asked an oddly-worded question (see [j6t's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195220/how-does-git-branching-work-in-this-case#comment124086708_70195220)).  As a result, you get a long answer.  Please read it carefully to see where what you're thinking is happening isn't what is actually happening in Git terminology, so that you can update your mental model and/or terminology.

I *think* I have provided the answer you are looking for, but it is hard to be sure.

## Long

> Let's say I have a repo "sample" with 2 branches "master" and "develop".

If you're using `git push`, you almost certainly have at least *two* repositories, not just one.

Let's say here that you have one local repository (e.g., on your laptop, where you do your day to day coding), and one hosting-site repository, on, e.g., GitHub.  Let's call that other repository the "shared repo" since you use it to send your updates to everyone else.

The *branch names* in your repository are yours, to do with as you will.  You might have `master` and `develop` and `feature-1` at this point.

The *branch names* in the *shared* repository belong to the shared repository.  These may be spelled the same—`master` and `develop`, for instance—as some of your branch names, but they are *their names*.

Each branch name, in any Git repository, holds the hash ID of exactly one commit.  Two or more branch names may hold the hash ID of a single commit, or there may be thousands of commits, and two names that hold just two of these IDs.  This works fine for Git because the purpose of a branch name is to help you and Git find a specific commit, but commits *also* find specific commits.

In particular, each commit you make remembers the hash ID of some set of previous commits.  Most commits hold exactly one previous hash ID, which we call the *parent* commit.  A few commits—merge commits—hold two parent hash IDs, and the very first commit ever has no parent, so its list of parent hash IDs is empty, but most commits just have the one.

What this means—which is the key to answering your question—is that *commits remember earlier commits* and *branch names are only used to remember the **last** commit in some chain of commits*.  That is, if we go to draw the commits and a branch name, we get pictures that look like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

or:

```
           master
              |
              v
... <-F <-G <-H <-I <-J
                      ^
                      |
                   develop
```

Note how each branch name *points to* one commit.  Each commit then points *backwards* to its *parent commit*.  The uppercase letters here, like `H`, stand in for Git's actual commit hash IDs, which are big, ugly, random-looking [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers that no human ever wants to use.

Commit `H` here is the *last* commit on branch `master`, even though it is not necessarily the last commit ever.  Commit `J` is the *last* commit on `develop` (and currently also the last commit ever).  Git works backwards, starting from `H`, when you look at `master`.  Git works backwards, starting from `J` (and reaching and working through `H`), when you look at `develop`.

(Each *commit* represents—and retains—a full snapshot of every file, plus the metadata that says who made it, when, and so on.  The metadata include the raw hash ID of the parent commit(s), which is *how* Git works backwards.  But you mostly just need to remember *that* Git works backwards.)

#### How cloning works, in a nutshell

You made your laptop repository by *cloning* the shared repository:

```
git clone -b somebranch <url>
```

When Git clones a repository, it copies *all of their commits* and *none of their branches*.  Instead, your Git *renames their branches* into your own *remote-tracking names*.  So if they had:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- develop
```

you get, in your clone at this point:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

Note how you have the exact same commits (which will have the exact same big ugly hash ID numbers), but you have no branch names at all, yet.

Before it quits, though, your `git clone` command *creates* one branch name in your clone.  The name it creates is the one you supply with your `-b` option.  If you didn't supply a `-b` option, your Git asks their Git—their software running on the shared repository site—what branch name *they* recommend (usually `master` or now `main`).  If you did use `-b`, you need to supply one of their branch names.  Your Git matches up this `-b` with their name—which is your `origin/` version now—and uses the *commit* found by this `origin`-ized name to create a *new branch name* in your repository, pointing to the *same commit*, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

#### How you use branch names while creating new commits

That `HEAD` notation I added here is how Git remembers *which of your branch names you are using*.  You pick out—or even create from scratch if you like—an existing branch name or a new branch name.  If you pick an existing branch name, you're picking an existing commit: whichever commit that branch name points to.  If you create a *new* name, you can pick out any existing commit, though the default is to use whichever commit you're already using.

Your Git now *extracts the commit* you chose, into a working area.  All commits are completely read-only, and the saved files inside those commits are in a format that only Git can read (and nothing can write once they've been saved).  So to *use* these files, Git has to extract them.  The extracted commit is now your *current commit*, with the branch name you chose being your *current branch name*.  The special name `HEAD` remember which branch name you're using, and the branch name remembers which commit you're using.  So that's why we drew:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

You're currently *using* commit `H`, through the name `master`.

If you now create a new branch name, such as `feature-1`, you choose which commit it should point-to, but the default is the current commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature-1, master (HEAD), origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

You can now switch *to* that branch:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature-1 (HEAD), master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

Note that you're still *using commit `H`*, but you're doing so via the name `feature-1` now.  (Since you did not change which commit you're using, Git doesn't bother removing and replacing any files, but if you were to create the name `feature-1` pointing to commit `G`, or commit `J`, Git would have to remove the commit-`H` files from your working area, and put in the other commit's files.)

You now go about making changes to working-tree files, and then you run `git add` to make Git prepare these updated files for a new commit.  (There's a lot to this, but we won't cover any the details here.)  You then run `git commit`.  Git will now make a *new commit*.  This new commit gets a new, unique, random-looking (but not actually random) hash ID.  We'll call this commit `K`, using the next uppercase letter:

```
             K   <-- feature-1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

New commit `K` points back to existing commit `H`.  That's `K`'s *parent*.  Git knows to do this because when you started the `git commit` command, the `HEAD` commit was commit `H`.

Now that commit `K` exists—has been made by running `git commit`—Git has stored the hash ID of commit `K` in the *name* `feature-1`.  So `feature-1` now points to commit `K`.  Commit `K` saves all the files—both the ones you *didn't* change, and the updated ones that you ran `git add` on—and since you `git add`-ed all your updates, commit `K` saves all the files from your working tree, forever (or for as long as commit `K` continues to exist anyway).  It's now safe for Git to *remove* these files from your working tree, if you change to some other commit.

If you go ahead and make more commits, they just add on as before:

```
             K--L   <-- feature-1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

Note how the *branch name*—**your** branch name; the name `feature-1` exists only in your own repository right now—always points to the *last* commit in the branch.  This happens automatically when you `git commit`, since Git *updates* the name to point to the new commit, which Git made point backwards to the old "last commit" in that branch.

#### What `git push` does

**Note: this doesn't match your description:**

> I work on "feature-1" and push my changes to the "develop" branch.

I'm going to describe how you'd push your new commits to `feature-1`, not to `develop`.

When you run `git push origin feature-1`, your Git software, operating on your repository—I'll call this "your Git"—does this:

- It calls up the other Git operating on the shared repository (I'll call this "their Git").
- It has them list out their branch names and commit hash IDs.  `feature-1` isn't in this list, but `master` and `develop` are, and they show commits `H` and `J` respectively, if nothing else has changed.
- Your Git now figures out which *new* commits you have, that they don't, that need to be sent.  This would be commits `K-L`.  Your Git uses the knowledge that, since they have commits up through `H` and `J`, you only have to send them any updates to any files that you changed or added in those two new commits.  This lets your Git send very little data, even if the commits contain thousands or millions of files, with many megabytes of data.
- Your Git then sends these commits.  (For some `git push` operations, there are no commits to send at all, but here that would be `K` and `L`.)
- Finally, your Git asks them to create or update *their* name `feature-1`, in *their* repository, to make it point to commit `L`.

Since they didn't have a `feature-1` yet, this create-or-update request means *create* and they may not even have to check whether this is a reasonable thing to do.  (Hosting sites often add a lot of checking that base Git doesn't normally do; e.g., GitHub offer *protected branches*.  Base Git just does a simple "does this update drop any commits off the end of the branch" check, which Git calls a *fast-forward* test, when you're updating rather than creating.)  Assuming they obey, which is likely, *they* now probably have:

```
             K--L   <-- feature-1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- develop
```

in *their* repository.  Note that the *commits* are literally identical.  their *branch names*, however, are theirs.  For instance, perhaps they have some new commits on *their* `master` and `develop` that you don't have yet:

```
             K--L   <-- feature-1
            /
...--F--G--H--M   <-- master
            \
             I--J--N   <-- develop
```

That's perfectly normal and OK: you've sent them your `K-L`, which they didn't have, and now they have your `K-L`.  You asked them to create the name `feature-1`, and they did, and their `feature-1` now points to their copy of `L`.  You did not ask them to change the hash IDs stored in their `master` and `develop`, and they did not, so they still have the commits they have.  They've merely added your two comits.

(If you want to get commits `M` and `N`, you would now run `git fetch origin`.  Your Git would call up their Git, see that they have `M` and `N` that you don't, and get `M` and `N` from them.  This process is identical to the one you used with `git push`.  But then your Git takes their `master` and `develop` names and *renames them* again, to `origin/master` and `origin/develop`.  Your Git then updates your `origin/master` and your `origin/develop`, to point to `M` and `N` respectively.  Of course, if they don't have any new commits—if `M` and `N` don't exist—you don't need to do any of this.  But you find out by running `git fetch`: `git push` doesn't tell you, even though it internally found out which commits they had, to be able to send just commits `K-L`.  There are complicated reasons for all of this and some of these details may be subject to change: the ones that aren't are that `git push` sends your new commits to them, and `git fetch` gets their new commits to you.)

#### Merging

Let's go back to this:

> I work on "feature-1" and push my changes to the "develop" branch.

You can, literally, run:

```
git push origin feature-1:develop
```

This has your Git send your commits (`K-L`) to their Git as before, but then instead of asking them to create or update their name `feature-1`, your Git will ask them to create or update their name `develop`.

Let's look at the graph we drew earlier, without the added `M` and `N` commits, but using their names and no `feature-1` yet:

```
             K--L   <-- polite request: make `develop` point to `L`
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- develop
```

This how their Git would see this `git push`.  It ends with a request: *Please, if it's OK, set your branch name `develop` to point to commit `L`*.

**This is not okay.**  If they did that, here's what they would have:

```
             K--L   <-- develop
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   ???
```

What happens to commits `I-J`?  The answer is: *they can no longer find them.*  Git *finds* commits by starting from a name and working backwards.  The only name they had that would find `J` was `develop`.  If they make their `develop` point to `L`, no amount of working *backwards* will ever find `I` or `J`.  The arrows in commits only point backwards.

(Remember, no part of any commit can ever change, once we make it.  So commit `H`, which points backwards to commit `G`, *can* point backwards to `G`: `G` existed when we made `H`.  But it *can't* point forwards to `I`, which didn't exist yet.  When we make our own `K`, `H` can't point forwards to `I` *or* `K`: it's set in stone and it points only backwards, to `G`.  So there's never any way to move forwards: Git can only work backwards.)

Now, if, when we started all this, their `master` and `develop` *both* pointed to `H`, and they still did when we ran:

```
git push origin feature-1:develop
```

then—in this particular case—we *could* add our commits on, because they would start with:

```
             K--L   <-- polite request to set develop here
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, develop
```

and setting `develop` would *not* lose any commits off the end, so they could do that.

Chances are, however, that this isn't what you did: instead, you probably just pushed `feature-1`.  If you're using GitHub or Bitbucket, you then made a *pull request*, which is a GitHub / Bitbucket feature.  If you're using GitLab, you then made a *merge request*, which is a GitLab feature.  Base Git doesn't have these things: hosting sites offer them as add-ons, to add value for people using these hosting sites.  (They all do it a little bit differently, too, so that you'll stick with *their* hosting.  But that's another matter entirely.)

These pull or merge requests eventually result in someone—maybe yourself—doing something with the hosting site to add new commits to some branch, by updating some branch name(s) in the hosting-site Git repository, and maybe copying the proposed-to-add commits to new and improved commits first, or adding a merge commit.  (Whether, when, and exactly how that happens is a topic for a separate discussion, tagged with the hosting site since each site does this a little differently.  Be sure to search StackOverflow for existing discussions here, as there are plenty.)

#### Back to your question

> I then work on "feature-2". How do I push just these changes to "master", without pushing "feature-1" as well?

When you run a second `git push`, your Git will, once again, send to their Git any new commits you have, that they don't.

Let's assume here that you started with this in your own repository:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

but you then made your `feature-1` so that it pointed to commit `J`, not `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- feature-1 (HEAD), origin/develop
```

You then made a commit `K`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/develop
                 \
                  K   <-- feature-1 (HEAD)
```

and used `git push origin feature-1` to send that to their (`origin`'s) Git repository.  Or, more likely, you started with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master, origin/develop
```

and ended with:

```
             I--J   <-- feature-1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master, origin/develop
```

You then were able to send commits `I-J` to their Git, to be merged or fast-forwarded or whatever into their `develop`.

You now want to start work on `feature-2`, which you intend to send to them such that they can easily add these commits to their `master`.  What you need, then, is to create your `feature-2` branch name pointing to the same commit that your `origin/master`—their `master`—points to.

In case that's been updated, it's a good idea to run `git fetch` at this point:

```
git fetch origin
```

This will collect any new commits they have and update your `origin/*` names.  If there are no new commits or updates on their end, nothing will change in your Git repository.  If there *are* some updates, you'll get any new commits and your `origin/*` names will get updated appropriately.

Next, you'll want to create your own `feature-2` name, pointing to the *same commit* as their `master`, i.e., your now-updated `origin/master`.  To do this, we can use:

```
git switch -c feature-2 --no-track origin/master
```

(the `--no-track` option is not really necessary here but in general it may be a good idea).  You will now have this:

```
             I--J   <-- feature-1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- feature-2 (HEAD), master, origin/master, origin/develop
```

This `git switch -c` command—or the equivalent `git checkout -b feature-2 --no-track origin/master`, if you have an older Git version—is a way to create a branch name, pointing to a particular commit (`origin/master`'s, or commit `H` in these drawings), and then `git switch` or `git checkout` *to* it, all in one go.  It's a shortcut for:

```
git branch feature-2 --no-track origin/master
git switch feature-2
```

Because you are switching branches, your Git will now *remove*, from your working tree, all the files that go with commit `J`—the commit that *was* `HEAD` just a moment ago—and replace them with all the files from commit `H`, to which the new name `feature-2` points.

You can now make new commits as usual.  The first such new commit's parent will be commit `H`, i.e., their `master` when you start out working:

```
             I--J   <-- feature-1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master, origin/develop
            \
             K   <-- feature-2 (HEAD)
```

A second commit will extend this branch in the obvious way:

```
             I--J   <-- feature-1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master, origin/develop
            \
             K--L   <-- feature-2 (HEAD)
```

Your *four* new commits, `I-J` and `K-L`, can all be sent to their Git repository at any time.  You can even push all four at once, creating names `feature-1` and `feature-2` in their Git repository:

```
git push origin feature-1 feature-2
```

Your Git figures out which commits you have that they don't (`I-J` and `K-L`, if you haven't sent `I-J` yet), sends those commits to their Git, and sends them *two* polite requests to create or update names `feature-1` and `feature-2` in *their* Git repository.

(You can then create two pull requests, or two merge requests, if that's appropriate.  Or, if you really are pushing directly to their `master` and `develop`, you can do that in one `git push` with:

```
git push origin feature-1:develop feature-2:master
```

As we noted before, these polite requests have their Git check to make sure that they won't lose any commits off the end of *their* branch names, if they make these updates.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. There was a bit of a gap in my terminology and Git's, but you've managed to answer all my queries.